# Google Spreadsheet script stops and gives "the execution time exceeded"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm doing a job where it contains a script to change data in a google spreadsheet column.

The script works in parts, it starts to run changing according to the column cell information, however when it arrives at a certain height it stops and gives execution time exceeded.

Here is the code:

```javascript
    var PlanImporte = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Importe");
    
    function modelaDataStatus() {  
      
      
      var DataStatus = PlanImporte.getRange(2, 5, PlanImporte.getLastRow()).getValues();
      
      
      for(var i = 0; i < DataStatus.length; i++){
      
        if(DataStatus[i] != ""){      
          
          var Dado = PlanImporte.getRange(i+2, 5).getValue();        
          PlanImporte.getRange(i+2, 5).setValue('Teste');
          
        }  
      
      }
      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

- From your code I understand that you want to replace the values with `'Teste'` if they are **not** empty. Otherwise keep the current value.
- The issue with your code is that you are iteratively using `getValue` and `setValue` which is a computational expensive approach and this is why your code fails to execute within the time limit.
- Instead, you can store the desired values (based on the condition I mentioned) to an empty array and then set the values of that array back to the sheet with one line of code:

  `PlanImporte.getRange(2,5,data.length,1).setValues(data);`
- I also improved your code by defining constant variables and also by using a more efficient and practical loop in this case which is [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- The [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) was used to replace the if condition.
- Since your data is part of a single column, I use [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert the 2D array returned by `getValues` to 1D.

---

### Solution:

```
function modelaDataStatus() {
const PlanImporte = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Importe");  
const DataStatus = PlanImporte.getRange(2, 5, PlanImporte.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
const data = [];  
DataStatus.forEach(r=>data.push(r!=''?['Teste']:[r]));
PlanImporte.getRange(2,5,data.length,1).setValues(data);
}
```